# Unable to save information to the database from custom sub-page at Wordpress Admin Panel

Tags: wordpress, custom-controls, admin

I'm developing a theme with a custom page with several sub-pages at the admin panel.
Weird but i got it working couple of times but the third time i couldn't make it work. 
The sub-page that is not working is where I'm trying to give the user the possibility of choosing which post-formats he wants to be activated.
The main problem (for starters) is that, even if the setting is registered successfully to the wp_options table, the information is not being saved and I don't know why.

[image]

I'll try to shorten the code specifically to that sub-page.
This code isn't finished, but it should be saving the data to the setting already.

```
      <?php 
  /* 
  @package sunset theme
  ================================
        ADMIN FUNCTIONS
  ================================
  */


  function sunset_add_admin_page () {

     // Suset Admin Page
     add_menu_page( 'Sunset Sidebar Options', 'Sunset', 'manage_options', 'sunset', 'sunset_theme_create_page', get_template_directory_uri().'/img/sunset-icon.png', 110 );    

     // Sunset Admin Sub-Pages 
     add_submenu_page( 'sunset', 'Sunset Theme Options', __('Theme Options','sunsetTheme'), 'manage_options', 'sunset_support_page', 'sunset_theme_support_page' );
 // I coded two other submenu pages which I omitted for clarity sake.

     // Activate Custom Settings

  add_action('admin_init' , 'sunset_custom_settings');

  add_action('admin_menu', 'sunset_add_admin_page');

  function sunset_custom_settings() {
  register_setting( 'sunset-theme-support' , 'post_formats' , 'sunset_post_formats_callback' );
     add_settings_section( 'sunset-theme-options', 'Theme Options', 'sunset_theme_options_section', 'sunset_support_page' );
     add_settings_field('post-formats' , __('Post Formats', 'sunsetTheme') , 'sunset_post_formats', 'sunset_support_page' , 'sunset-theme-options');

  }

  ///////////////////  POST FORMATS    /////////////////////////

  // Post formats callback

  function sunset_post_formats_callback($input) {
     return $input;   
  }

  // Post formats Section 

  function sunset_theme_options_section() {
     echo '<h4>Activate and De-activate specific Theme Support Options</h4>';
  }

  // Post-formats field
  function sunset_post_formats() {
  $formats = ['aside' , 'audio' , 'chat' , 'gallery' , 'image' , 'link' , 'quote' , 'status' , 'video'];
     $output = '';
     foreach ($formats as $format) {
        $output .= '<label><input id="' . $format . '" type="checkbox" value="1" name="post_formats[' . $format . ']">'. ucfirst($format) . '</label><br>';
     }
     echo $output; 
  }

  function sunset_theme_support_page() {
     require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/templates/sunset_theme_support.php';
  }
```

The template sunset_theme_support_page() looks like this:

```
      <h1>Sunset Support Options</h1>
  <?php settings_errors();
  //  $firstName = esc_attr(get_option( 'first_name' )) ;
  ?>  
  <form method="post" action="options.php" class="form-formats-options">
     <?php settings_fields( 'sunset-theme-support' ); ?>
     <?php do_settings_sections( 'sunset_support_page' ); ?>
     <?php submit_button() ; ?>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

*******SOLVED*******

Apparently over the years something changed and now you have to go `exit;` at the end of the callback in order to work

```
  function sunset_post_formats_callback($input) {
       return $input;
       exit;   
  }
```